# rename the header of the spliting group in r

Tags: r

Im wondering how to change the header name of splitted group.

```
original_string <- c("x=2", "y=2","z=34")  
splt <- strsplit(original_string, "=")  
r<- lapply(splt, function(x) assign(x[1], as.numeric(x[2]), envir = globalenv()))  
d1 <- data.frame(r)
d1
```

output:

```
   X2 X2.1 X34
1  2    2  34
```

Is it possible to rename the header like:

```
  Tom Jerry Jane  
1  2    2    34
```

How can I make it ? 
Thank a lot.

Comment: Why are you assigning the values to the global environment if you are just going to do `data.frame(r)` in the end?

Comment: You can do: `data.frame("names<-"(lapply(splt, `[`, 2), c("Tom", "Jerry", "Jane")))` in your "r" line to get that `data.frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
setNames(d1, c('Tom', 'Jerry', 'Jane'))
```

Or

```
colnames(d1) <- c('Tom', 'Jerry', 'Jane')
```

Comment: _Error in setNames(v1, c("Tom", "Jerry", "Jane")) : object 'v1' not found_
It seems doesn't work.

Comment: @yxcao I renamed the object as `d1 <- data.frame(r1)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_frame(variable_value = original_string) %>%
  separate(variable_value,
           c("variable", "value")) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1) %>%
  spread(variable, value) %>%
  rename(Tom = x, 
         Jerry = y, 
         Jane = z)
```

Comment: I've added a rename statement. The variables already have semantically meaningful names, x, y, and z. The disadvantage of the setNames method is that it relies on the order of variables in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

I see you created a dataframe. You can change the titles of the columns with

```
names(df) # this shows what the names are
```

and with

```
names(df) <- c("Tom", "Jerry", "Jane") #you change the names
```